# Purging Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, stack-exchange, maintenance

What is the position on purging old answers that receive little or negative response. What benefit does it serve to keep answers that are downvoted numerous times (resulting in negative scores), or answers that have no upvotes/downvotes and exist for well over a year?

Is there any reason to keep these types of answers around for a length of time? Seems like they only add noise.

#### Grounds for purging:

1. Answer is older than n-months
2. Answer is not accepted
3. Answer has negative score with primarily downvotes
4. ...what would you suggest?

#### Alternative

Answers aren't purged. Instead, they are hidden and aren't shown until the reader explicitly requests "answers older than n-months."

Comment: (-1) for the reasons in my response.

Comment: what does the age of an answer have to do with anything? why isn't sorting good enough - why do we need to hide these?

Comment: Sort along the z-axis and we'll both be happy ;)

Comment: Standard blow-off answer: write a greasemonkey script to do it!

Comment: -1 Because While it's helpful to see the right answer, it's very helpful to see what the community disapproves of. If I had my way, the owner of a post could disassociate themselves (and regain the rep-lost from downvotes), but the answer would stay, as a warning towards others.

Comment: @Gortok, what percentage of the users do you think really want to dig into wrong answers, when they have the right answers directly in front of them?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - No clue. However, the percentage of "This is the canonical way of doing *X*" answers are very small. Most times there are *n*-number of ways of doing something; and it's good to know what the community thinks is the Best, the Better, and the Please-Don't-Do-It-This-Way answer. Sometimes there are architectural considerations that prevent the 'best' way from being done, and being able to fall back on the lesser means helps.

Comment: @Gortok, good points. But if I encountered an architectural issue that wouldn't allow me to implement any of the top few answers, I would probably create a new question including my architectural-difference rather than digging through many other answers that may by chance assume my unique environment.

Comment: I've not done that, only because I don't want people to say the obvious ("Well, just change the architecture!"). There are days you can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way answers are sorted solves the noise issue. I don't think there's really any benefit to purging.

Comment: If an answer has 10 responses, and only one is worth keeping, why keep the other 9? You could save a tremendous amount of storage.

Comment: Storage is cheap. The negative karma resulting from deleting my answers is not.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you should be punished if your answer is purged. If it wasn't accepted, and received only negative attention - your karma is already bad :)

Comment: I can delete if I so choose. I don't want the system to delete it for me just because it had few (or no) votes. If the post was counter-productive, then it can be flagged and removed by a mod.

Comment: Purged answers would only be answers that are bad. If you have bad answers, you've already be sufficiently punished. If anything, the purge would save you from further punishment.

Comment: What's a "bad" answer? If it's inappropriate, then flag it. If it's just a less-than-ideal solution - it still serves a purpose as a reader can see that it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Jonathan, how can you determine that the answers are 'bad' is this a manual determination? Or is there an algorithm that determines an intrinsic level of *good* that is inherent in each response.

Comment: @devinb, similar to how we determine users are bad with the flagging system. By the number of votes to score.

Comment: @Jonathan: If posts are flagged, then there is a process for deleting them. Flags are *very* different than downvotes. Especially on MSO downvotes do not mean that something is wrong. It means 'disagreed with', and we can't just delete all the people we disagree with.

Comment: @devin, I'm speaking in the context of SO, where downvotes typically do mean something is wrong (except in the case of 'what's your favorite cartoon').

Answer (score 2):

I do not think we should be removing old answers based on score.

On the issue of noise, they don't actually add noise if you are in the 'votes' view, because there are simply at the bottom of the page, so they will only bother you if you voluntarily go to view them.

In terms of the actual removing of the answers, this is a very bad idea. We have in general no idea why this specific answer was downvoted. Starting with an example from MSO ([Is "Don't Do It" a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer/8922#8922)) That question has a negative score for me. It does not mean that my answer is bad, offensive, wrong, or awfully written. It simply means that the sum of people viewing the question disagreed with me. It is important to keep these answers around, because it articulates both sides of the debate. If you delete all the MSO answers with a negative score, you'll end up with a lot of one sided debates, and no real learning.

On the SO side, I have two responses with negative votes.

[Algorithms: interesting diffing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835143/algorithms-interesting-diffing-algorithm/835235#835235)

In this case, the OP (or someone tactical) downvoted almost every answer, even though I made a few edits in direct response to the author, and ended up providing code that did exactly what was required (and updating it as the OP repeatedly edited the question). I don't feel that I deserved the downvote, but that is the way it goes sometimes. However, if that were to get *deleted* because it has a downvote, I'd consider that offensive.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942421/are-endless-loops-in-bad-form/942496#942496) question as well, I was voted down twice for presenting an opinion that was contrary to other people's beliefs. Again, I don't mind the downvotes, but I maintain that my answer should be there for people to read. Even if they disagree, they will be better off if their assumptions are challenged, rather than pretending that there is no opposition.

Even 'bad' answers are educational, because they provide "patterns to avoid".

Answer (score 1):

If negative, it might show you what not to do, not to say, or have a certain bad opinion. It is beneficial sometimes to know at least that.

Less responsive or low vote answers might provide alternatives that might not be as popular, but still possibly beneficial to anyone looking at the question.

Any duplicates or the same idea or "what he said" answers could just be deleted though.

Comment: From a behavioral standpoint, I don't think people come here looking for downvoted answers.

Comment: And they won't see them unless they scroll all the way to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: ...or they're hidden completely until explicitly requested?

Comment: Well they won't be looking for them, but they could find some value in them if they want to. Like Jon said too, there at the bottom and only there if you scroll down. (that takes some people a lot of effort) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Purging answers with negative scores will inherently improve someone's rep after a recalc which I think is contrary to the whole notion of negative rep.  Negative rep is there to show that folks don't agree with that person.  In order to show that, all history needs to be maintained (with obvious exceptions for abuse, offensive, etc etc).  Without the negative rep you don't get the full picture

Comment: If I delete my own negative scored answers doesn't that have the same consequence?

Comment: @squillman, Note that when I say "purge," I don't insist that the records must be physically deleted. Perhaps just made invisible.

Comment: @Jon B: Yes, true, but I hold that you have that right as the owner of that post. Autopurging is a different story in my book

Comment: @Jonathan: Ok, then the rep thing becomes moot :)