# Is it OK for us to give advice but not actually answer the users question? ex: (how can I do X? answer: don't do it)

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “Don’t do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Often times I see a user asking how to do something that is not a good idea, for example: [how do I make radio buttons looks like checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616212/can-i-make-wpf-radiobuttons-look-like-checkboxes/1616222#1616222) (my answer: don't, it will just confuse your users) I sometimes post an answer that tells them that its probably not a good idea. This allows us to give our opinions and try to help them in ways they might not have directly asked for. Someone else usually posts how to actually perform the non-reccommended answer, so I figure no harm done. When my answer is upvoted to the top of the list, it shows that people agree with it and its good practice. If not, (how do I get syntax highlighting in MSWord? my answer: just use notepad) then it may get downvoted, but it will be discussed and the user will learn from our discussion (and I can delete it if it isn't helpful at all). Is this ok?

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer - but the answer is "yes", as long as you back it up

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why not. When people are trying to figure out [how to hammer a nail with an old shoe](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx), they really need to be told there is a better tool.