# Should my answer cover every last possibility given the question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I just noticed on different places that some answers are quite specific to the question that was asked and they have been downvoted because of not covering the more detailed part.

For example, an answer regarding how to split strings was posted. The answer was perfectly right but hadn't considered **the rule of "never trust what has been submitted"** and the answer was marked negatively.

As I am new to Stack Overflow, what is the standard when you answer a question? Should you include a complete scenario taking into account even the smallest part?

Comment: I don't see a question here. Can you provide 1. an example, 2. what the community did, and 3. what you expected instead?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I tried to explain in second paragraph what i had seen however i did not keep reference sorry for that

Comment: you can use the "edit" link to add a reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "Don't do it" a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A concrete example we can look at in context would be helpful ;p

From the "never trust what has been submitted", I'm reading between some lines - which *may be the wrong lines*; if this relates to something that could cause SQL injection, for example, then the answer is (IMO) dangerously wrong  **even if it does exactly what the OP asked**. Sometimes the correct answer is "well, you *could* do this via [blah], but that would be dangerous because [blah]; instead, it is preferable to [blah] because [blah]".

If somebody is asking (without realising it) how to shoot themselves in the foot, then giving them a loaded gun is not the correct answer.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. I wish people would stop handing out those loaded guns though....

Comment: Thanks Marc, you are right. Now I am quite clear on situation why those answers had been marked negatively. But I guess these message should be communicated clearly before new user start using system. Reason after that is, if someone just start participating forum, then it's really hard to make sure that your answer is not loaded gun without paying some specific attention on that.

Comment: @tejash - but that applies to most of reality, not just internet-based programming sites. If there is enough context to see that something is a very bad idea, you would say, no? Like "I've got headache that is 4 times worse than the last one I had; last time I took 2 paracetamol and it got better; do you have 8 paracetamol please?"

Comment: Yes you are right. But that depends on person how he understand some one's advise. Some one asked that he had a headache than you can suggest paracetamol, Normally you will not clarify that do not take 8 paracetamol if its 4 time worse than last time. So for a quick reply you are going to say use text posted through form and you provide some code snippet. But I guess we can not take granted other important items and we should describe importance of validating input or sql injection etc

Comment: @tejash can you show a real life example?

Comment: one of example i noticed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241739/insert-in-database-from-each-line-of-textarea-field-by-php Answer given by Dvir Azulay has been voted -1  before, but now its 0. Have a look

Comment: @tejash actually it is +2-2=0, but that still means that Dvir has gained by posting it. And the comments discuss 2 different potential issues for others to read and decide whether it applies to them. All in all, that looks pretty healthy to me: via the comments, the "it works" is notes, the "but watch for this" is noted, and the poster (Dvir) has net gain..

Answer (score 0):

How to split a string has been asked a bazillion times already. Just answering the question (again, and again) instead of linking to [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c), is high risk.

If you do that in the C++ section, and give one of the dangerous C solutions, you really risk your own foot as well.