# Is it okay for people to question your choices / practices which aren't related to the question?

Tags: discussion, comments

I get it a lot - people asking me in the comments why I choose to do something a certain way when I "should" be doing it another way. Things that aren't a matter of working better/worse, but a matter of personal flavor.

For example, in [one question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505417/integer-function-result-value-assigned-to-function-name-never-used), I'm using OLE automation to unzip a compressed file. Someone commented asking me and I quote:

> "Why would you choose to unzip this way when Delphi has built in libraries? And tpAbbrevia. And so on. And why would GetLastError be meaningful here? I see no reason to believe that."

In my thoughts, my responses come to mind...

- Maybe because I'm looking for minimal compiled output file size?
- Maybe because I'm learning and experimenting with OLE automation?
- Maybe because I'm not happy with the built-in libraries?
- Maybe because I've just never heard of it?
- Maybe because I've been assigned this task by a higher authority?
- Maybe because I need to support versions of Delphi which didn't come with those libraries?

As you can see, the comment has absolutely nothing to do with the question (at least the first part of it). If questions get closed because of being "opinionated", then shouldn't comments qualify for similar rules? If the commenter was new to Stack Overflow and didn't understand the guidelines, I would understand and wouldn't say anything about it. But the user who posted that comment is extremely active on Stack Overflow with almost 250k rep, and has criticized my choices on many other things, [like this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694894/using-an-inherited-list-of-objects). There have been many other occasions but I'm not about to compile a list of everything. And it's not just this particular user, but a majority have been this particular user. Nothing against that user, my concern is as a whole.

It's similar to someone saying "Why don't you drive a Mercedes instead of a Chevy?" or "You should be living in a house, not an apartment." or "Dogs are a better pet than cats."

So should this type of unrelated criticism be allowed? I do appreciate the input. but it's often very frustrating when someone seems to keep looking for reasons to criticize everything I do - specifically when it has nothing to do with the question. Perhaps users could at least re-word their comments to be less insulting?

Comment: Loads of questions on Stack Overflow are born out of ignorance on the asker's part, and questioning their basic assumptions is the best thing you can do to help them. I know it feels slightly insulting if you really know what you are doing and have a good reason to do things a specific way, but there is no way for us to tell one apart from the others. Just ignore the sometimes abrasive-sounding tone, and calmly give as much explanation as you care to give. Who knows - maybe you'll discover a better way to solve your problem? It happens to all of us.

Comment: yes it is ok, but you don't have to respond.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Pëkka I'm not understanding how that's related, can you elaborate? I asked about X, but user is commenting asking me about M. What is M? Exactly my point - it's not a part of the question.

Comment: The XY problem is when a person gets on the train in Boston heading to DC, and asks why they can't continue to Chicago from there without going through Phillie. A comment along the lines of "why the heck are you going to DC anyways?" is often step one in resolving the whole problem. This seems to be directly analogous to the comment you're highlighting here, although I don't know enough about the subject matter to say for sure.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Except the question is in no way related to OLE automation or unzipping a file. It has to do with the way that functions work. It just so happened that my example code included some unrelated stuff.

Comment: Like I said, that may be so in this case; I don't know. In many other cases, though, the asker has buried herself in a hole that she didn't need to dig in the first place. Readers don't know that any of your bullet points are true, and if any of them _isn't_ (especially number 4), then the best answer may be to suggest [an entirely different approach](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179567/). If you're having trouble manually doing something complex and there's a library function to do it, wondering why you're not using the library seems completely reasonable to me.

Comment: @Jerry: Except it makes sense to ask, especially in this case. "I'm doing something that my language has native, built in support for in a way that is much more difficult, and I'm checking an error code that has no applicability to my code." (COM doesn't use SetLastError, so checking results using GetLastError makes no sense.) I understand the comment perfectly, and would have asked it myself if someone else hadn't. How are we to know it's not just an uninformed choice on your part?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Allowed? What process could disallow it?

However. Note that you are here asking for free assistance from everyone else. Having to read comments questioning your methodology seems a small price to pay. Heck, having to read comments questioning your *haircut* would be a small price to pay.

Nothing forces you to respond to these items. In some cases you'll get more or better answers if you do, but in other cases not.

Comment: My *haircut* in the pic is in fact not actually me :-) +1

Comment: Hah! That's what they all say. Is that a fez?