# I answered a possible duplicate question on Meta

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, etiquette

I think I answered a duplicate, or perhaps its not a direct duplicate. The question is asking about a specific case, but the question has been answered in a more general/less localized way already.

It seems Meta is more tolerant of these cases, so I'm not sure what to do.

Should I voluntarily delete my answer and re-post it on the more general question, wait and see if the question gets flagged as a dup. and hope that my answer gets merged to the more general question, or just leave it alone?

Comment: Can you link these questions?

Comment: @djechlin http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179543/is-it-ok-to-give-suggestion-to-op-to-change-his-approach-for-making-a-new-answer

Possible dup. of-

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143940/when-is-it-acceptable-to-answer-a-question-that-wasnt-asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never delete your answer on a duplicate anyway.  If it's a duplicate, close as duplicate (in your case, flag).  If you can answer the original question, then do that.

More answers is generally okay as long as via duplicate-closures it's clear which one is best or canonical.  But *all* SE networks are tolerant of extra answers before a question is closed as duplicate.  Especially because they are often quite helpful before the duplicate is found.

On meta the only extra concern is we often need canonical answers to use as reference in future discussion / debate.  But duplicates imply a clear canonical answer, so it's still fine.