# Precise answer vs. approach changing suggestion

Tags: discussion

I got a bit confused after proposing an answer for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16552051/2319383). Author of that question asks if something is possible. Situation he described seems to be an example of rather bad approach in the beginning, but it happened - he or she asked a question "is it possible?". So I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16552307/2319383) that it is, stated that this may be too complicated and (or "but" ?!) proposed a solution (actually, two). And I got downvoted.
So my question is: should our answers be precise or should we rather alter the requirements for the question (as downvoter did in his answer) to suggest changing the general approach?

Comment: Well, you say it is possible, but never explain how. You completely skirt that issue and give other options. I can only assume readers of the question and your answer didn't like the evasion, or disagree on it being too complicated.

Comment: There were helpful comments on your answer.  Take them into consideration.

Comment: Yes, I know my proposed duplicate seems a bit out there but your questions are identical. Simply put, if you want to let the OP do something stupid then that's fine, but if you want to avoid downvotes as well it's best to explain why it's impractical and show them what they should be doing instead and _why_.

Comment: :-) @RobertHarvey, it makes perfect sense... just because all the words are different doesn't mean the questions aren't duplicates. The OP has an identical problem.

Comment: Related: [How do I tell a user that they are out of their depth?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116585/147191)

Answer (score 1):

Votes aren't there to represent * correctness* or whether or not you answered the question.  As the tooltip indicates, it's whether or not an answer is "useful".  This is (quite purposefully) very subjective.  There is no single objective metric that you can use to determine how to vote.  It is up to each user to vote on what they personally feels is and is not useful.  The result of this is "community values" based on what more people tend to find helpful and not helpful.  These community values can be very confusing, can seem arbitrary, be inconsistent, and can change, sometimes quickly, and sometimes radically.

The voting patterns of the community are different from the community guidelines with respect to other decisions such as which questions should be closed/open or what type of answers are allowable.  In those cases it's important that the result not be everything I described earlier (confusing, inconsistent, unstable) and so when the community settles on values there are moderators there to ensure that there not be [much] deviation from those community values.

So, what does this mean for you.  Well, the easiest answer is just to experiment.  Spend some time lurking; see what different people do and how people's votes seem to react.  Try doing different things on your end and see how the voters react.  When there are downvotes that indicate you're doing something wrong look for comments to indicate what you should fix (there won't always be, and they may not always be right, so sometime you will need to guess).

At the end of the day also keep in mind that having a few downvoted posts isn't the end of the world.  It's a learning opportunity; treat it as such.  Learn how to make better posts and value the opportunity to improve as both a programmer and an answerer.  Don't take it personally and get upset.

Comment: thanks for that answer. I will try to keep it in mind.