# Automatically warn against the use of mysql_* functions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, warning

Would it be possible to put a small warning on all questions that get tagged with [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) warning against the use of `mysql_*` functions in their code?

It seems that every single time a PHP/MySQL question is asked, there is an immediate comment warning of the dangers of using mysql_* functions. This seems very redundant and pointless, when we could notify the users upfront.

[image: All-too-common comment on PHP/MySQL questions on StackOverflow]

Does anyone have another idea on how to combat the pointlessness of these comments being posted constantly?

Comment: THis would be a good addition to the pro-forma comments system that seems to be in the works (no idea when it'll come though)

Comment: Why not for everything that becomes deprecated? Don't put ceilings on your dreams

Comment: Not sure how sarcastic I should perceive that comment to be...

Comment: @David If it's your question, not at all, if it's someone else's question, very.

Comment: That is quite possibly the best answer I could have expected.

Comment: It bugs me to read that comment on every MySQL question that uses the old mysql_ functions. Maybe the OP for one reason or another doesn't have access to the newer functions. Even though the mysql_ functions are "discouraged", they're not obsolete or verboten.

Comment: @j08691 that's very true, but I'm willing to bet with 99% of questioners it's just a case of a bad tutorial (see below)

Comment: Can someone explain why I've received two downvotes for this? (Used to be at +2)

Comment: @Pekka - possibly, but I think there's a difference between discouraging bad coding practices and/or protecting against SQL injections, and making blanket recommendations against using older functions for nothing other than a knee-jerk reaction to seeing the OP using them. It's obviously possible to write clean, secure code using the older mysql_ functions, and while I totally agree with using the newer mysqli_ and PDO options, the comment usually doesn't help the OP.

Comment: @j08691 I agree with your conclusion, albeit for different reasons (see below)

Comment: @David Most likely because some disagree. (Downvotes often [indicate disagreement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) on Meta SO)

Comment: @j08691 You are right, but I have yet to see an example of `"clean, secure code using the older mysql_ functions"` in a question, which is why I nearly always post that comment on those types of questions. Maybe I just see the wrong questions.

Comment: @David Because [the system encourages people to explain if a question can be improved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/140951) (which is usually the source of downvotes) commenting on downvotes (or asking about why someone downvoted you) is considered *noise* and is usually removed.

Comment: This is a slippery slope.  There are loads of deprecated functions and practices, covering every conceivable programming language, tool and library.  Are we going to cover all of them?

Comment: @David That said, in this case, I'll throw you a bone; I definitely downvoted, but [on Meta, downvoting is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  I disagree with the comment being on *every single question* I see.  At this point, it's useless noise and we're not doing anyone any good.  We want to think we're making all database access more secure, but we're really just wasting keystrokes and getting all happy because we think we told someone we know better when in reality, we have no clue what their situation is and how it applies. It's a mutual comment upvote thing.

Comment: It's a half thing when you read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer

Comment: Disagree. Why would PHP's `mysql_` functions get special treatment? Shouldn't the site automatically warn you when you're using `split`? or any of the other *hundreds* of deprecated PHP functions? And why stop at PHP? What about deprecation warnings for Perl? Ruby? Python? C? Why stop at deprecation warnings? And what about false-positives, where somebody asks "I've heard that the `mysql_*` functions are, bad what should I use to replace them?" And who decides on which specific functions get a warning and which don't? Who maintains the list of deprecated functions?

Comment: The (semi-)logical extreme would be piping every piece of code submitted to the site through a linter and spitting comments back at the user. It's not the job of the site to try and *automatically* spot bad code. That's what the users are for.

Comment: Also I assume you meant every question tagged both [tag:mysql] *and* [tag:php] in which the string `mysql_*` appears? Obviously posting such a notice for a question tagged [tag:mysql] and [tag:performance] or a question specifically about PDO would be pretty obnoxious.

Comment: I apologize for causing such a rift in the universe here. I have flagged my question to be closed.

Comment: @David It's not a _bad_ question, people just disagree with your premise ([voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)). Why delete it?

Comment: @David you have not caused any kind of rift. People downvote things they disagree with on Meta. It isn't personal and you shouldn't take it as such.

Comment: Well I've had one upvote and (as of this comment) eleven downvotes. Obviously the _vast_ majority of this community does not agree with my opinion; subsequently, it should be closed.

Comment: I think we should leave deprecation warnings to the language. *When* they acually materialize. Those comments are overly hyperbolic and undermine their actual security credibility with that deprecation speculation. (Use of the mysql_ functions has been discouraged since at least php 4.3, btw). They're also not helpful to newcomers. Link broadsides are seldomly relevant to people who haven't looked into the manual for a while.

Comment: Why the hell are people downvoting this ? The totally wrong people are running META...

Answer (score 20):

There's a lot of related questions coming in so this request makes sense, but on second thought, I'm starting to think it doesn't really matter whether we tell people not to use `mysql` or not.

The vast majority of users who present mysql_* code have copy-pasted it from some crappy tutorial and are going through the first steps of learning programming. They will not heed the PDO advice. They will not add error checking to their code. They just want to know why it doesn't *work* and what they need to do to make it work.

If they eventually evolve professionally, they will find out that it's deprecated quickly enough (e.g. by looking in the manual). SO can't be responsible for every  crappy tutorial out there. I mean, W3Schools sports SQL injection vulnerabilities in its examples [**to this day**](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/getcustomer.asp?q=norts%E2%80%99).

Look at [this work of beauty](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) for example:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];

... some code in which they connect to the DB, but do NOT escape $q ......

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

That infernal piece of crap site *alone* leads to more bad code than SO can ever fix.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. My point is, saving commenters the process of posting a pointless comment may be advantageous for the site.

Comment: @David I totally understand that, and I don't disagree. Don't get me wrong, I've been posting that comment a lot, too ... but I'm starting to tend more towards "it's pointless to comment in the first place"

Comment: Most of the people who ask a question with a `mysql_*` function have less than 100 rep, anyway, making it, like you said, extremely pointless.

Comment: I love the examples you see with something like this: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = " . $_POST['name']);`

Comment: @Pekka WOW. That w3 link is revolting! How can they do that to beginners! I'm pretty sure i've copied w3 stuff when I first started...

Comment: I actually want to visit the sites of these people and SQL inject it to teach them a lesson. Happened to me in the very beginning. I learned my lesson about validating input.

Answer (score 1):

There, done. This is now part of [the MySQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info) for those who so venture to read that page:

> #### Deprecation of mysql_ functions
>
> PHP functions that start with mysql_ have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the MySQLi or PDO extensions instead.

But you can only help those who want to be helped or are empowered to effect the change you want to Michael Jackson circa 1988.

Answer (score -2):

Comments like that are just noise and should be flagged as such. They don't help answer the question. It's equivalent to asking:

> Where can I get a BLT sandwich?

And the comment is:

> Bacon is unhealthy. You shouldn't eat meat. I'm a vegetarian.

Comment: Are you active enough in that particular tag to be able to judge this?

Comment: @Pekka That's my opinion on all "You shouldn't" comments that don't help answer the question.

Comment: Strongly, *strongly* disagree. If people were posting "dont' use mysql_*" as an *answer*, you would be exactly correct. But posting "you shouldn't do this" messages as comments is not only acceptable, it's a *good* practice and should be encouraged. It's a great thing when you can save somebody from introducing some terrible code to their app, or point out a potential pitfall they're going to face. Why in the world would you want to stand by and let somebody shoot themselves in the foot, knowing full-well that they're going to hurt themselves  and that you could prevent it?

Comment: @meagar It's difficult know an OP's situation well enough from just their question (nor should they have to explain it) to say whether or not they should or should not be doing something.

Comment: No, It's really not, I and many others have been doing it for years now and haven't had any trouble with it. Sometimes it doesn't take deep knowledge of somebody's code to see that they're introducing terrible bugs via a single line or short snippet of notoriously broken code.

Comment: And your example is utter pants. It would be more like somebody asking "Where can I get some bleach and toilet bowl cleaner to whiten my toilet?" and you responding "Don't do that, bleach and toilet bowl cleaner [mix to create toxic chloromine gas fumes](http://www.ehow.com/about_5455455_danger-mixing-bleach-toilet-cleaner.html), you're going to kill yourself". You're saving somebody from a concrete, factual, unambiguously *bad* thing that they are almost certainly ignorant of. "Bacon is unhealthy" is your opinion, and obviously forcing your unsolicited opinion on others is pretty unwelcome.

Comment: @meagar Those are good points and in the example in this question the comment was very well written and friendly. But many times comments like this are not like that. They are often rude and "You're doing it wrong, idiot." sounding. I have a bias against them.

Comment: Your example would be valid if I asked "I'd like to make a game using C++" and somebody commented "C++ is bloated. You shouldn't use it. I only program in C". See, that's unsolicited holier-than-though opinion, and it makes you an ass. Telling somebody that a deprecated function is deprecated is *not* opinion, it's fact, and it is not comparable.

Comment: If you think their comment is rude, flag it as rude. A moderator would instantly delete a "you're doing it wrong idiot" comment. We have a whole rule in the faq about that, and a whole "rude or offensive" flag to deal with it. It has nothing to do with the topic at hand.

Comment: @meagar Just because a function is deprecated doesn't it shouldn't be used. The OP could be working on legacy code on a server that can't be updated. So saying it's deprecated is not an opinion, but saying they OP shouldn't use it is.

Comment: "You shouldn't use deprecated functions" is not opinion. That's *why* functions are deprecated, that's literally the entire meaning of deprecating a function: Stop using it, it's going away. If the OP wants to head off such comments, he should indicate that he's working with legacy code either in the question or in a comment. I would expect the same from somebody posting obvious buffer-overflow or divide-by-zero errors; if they don't want obvious errors to become the focus of their question, they need to make us aware that *they* are aware.

Comment: @Pekka I agree with your answer. It's pointless for the reasons you listed. And if it's pointless, I think it's noise. I also agree I don't know anything about this `mysql_*` issue or its context. But comments like this set the tone for the question in a negative way to everyone that sees it after the comment. It would be simple enough to *answer the question* the way you think it should be done and *also* mention why the way they wanted to do it is not a good idea. The comment by itself doesn't add anything.