# Inform new posters tagging VB.NET to Check Option Strict Setting

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see loads of posts in VB.NET concerning runtime errors and the like that would not occur if Option Strict was switched on.

In the interests of improving everyones VB.NET code could SO pop up a message to say "Check you have Option Strict On" when they post their first question tagged VB.NET (It is off by default)

For anyone reading this who is not that familiar with VB.NET here are some useful links:

[Why should you switch Option Strict On](http://www.getdotnetcode.com/gdncstore/free/Articles/OPTION%20STRICT%20ON.htm)

[Option Strict Statement on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This does sound reasonable. Many bugs here that I've seen can be solved (at least for me) just by switching to `Option Strict` and with a little bit of modification

Comment: Is it at least mentioned in the tag wiki?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically warn against the use of mysql_* functions on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143379/automatically-warn-against-the-use-of-mysql-functions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: This could be a duplicate of a more general, "Warn users of dangerous coding practices when posting" feature request.  But closing as a duplicate of that other question doesn't really accomplish anything =/

Comment: @random - I added it and someone else removed it during an edit.

Answer (score 14):

It's unlikely that we'll ever introduce tag triggered click through barriers for new users.

People that don't bother to search prior to asking are just going to click through and ask anyway. This leaves the other group that actually did their homework to get annoyed at a barrier telling them to do something they've already done, or that doesn't apply to their question at all.

That means, at best, the feature would not work as intended, or get in the wrong person's way. If you couple that with how difficult it would be to implement, it just doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Incidentally, this was proposed a long time ago and rejected. I can't find the original, however - and I'm quite certain that it's subsequently been deleted. If memory serves, it also exampled VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how it works.  There are *questions* from VB.NET programmers that have their code blow up because they turned off static type checking.  Which is no different from questions by other users that use a dynamic language like Python or Ruby.  The SE engine cannot reasonably filter such questions, it can't compile and run the code from a missing or incomplete snippet.  The Option Strict setting is a Visual Studio setting anyway, it wouldn't appear in a snippet.

An *answer* that has an obvious bug that will cause code to crash at runtime is just a plain bad answer.  You should downvote it.