# Should we have a notice about the deprecated items, such as mysql_ functions?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically warn against the use of mysql_* functions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143379/automatically-warn-against-the-use-of-mysql-functions-on-stack-overflow)

I've seen several questions now where the code includes deprecated functions.

I'll use Mysql_ function for this example... The user posts a question with deprecated mysql_, and immediately several people respond with "don't use that, use PDO or Mysqli"...

Would it be useful to have Stackoverflow to search keywords and give a notice to the user that certain terms are no longer valid to save trouble? The notice would of course include an comprehensive explanation, along with links to better alternatives... I think this would save a lot of hassle.

Here are two recent examples I've seen:

[MySQL select query, retrieve data from more than one column by typing more than one word in search bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405688/mysql-select-query-retrieve-data-from-more-than-one-column-by-typing-more-than)

[Is this PHP code SQL vulnerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247260/is-this-php-code-sql-vulnerable/14247388#14247388)

Comment: @Bart Why is a question like this downvoted? Is it not useful? That guy got downvoted 11.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta are sometimes used to indicate disagreement. It is explained in this site's faq. Don't worry about it.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that it's Stack Overflow's job to assertively notify users about the current state of their programming language / context.  The best way to handle this is is as it's currently done - posters providing tips/advice in comments and answers.

If a user has a question about best practices, they should write and ask a question (a constructive, focused, on-topic question).

Comment: Fair enough. I thought it would be a good way to steer users in the right direction quicker, as well as filter out redundant questions to make room for unique and actually helpful questions.