# FAQ request: Performance of unoptimized code

Tags: feature-request

I'm not sure what is the procedure to improve the FAQ...

It is quite annoying to see repeated questions posting some code and measurements -- then eventually revealing that unoptimized compile was used.

Most comments will certainly go around that point, and answers turn out irrelevant once optimizaitions are turned on, as they should have been in the first place.

Those threads are hardly ever constructive, with the only thing to (re)learn is that raw/debug compile is no good for performance measurements and tweaking.

I suggest to put that category in the FAQ as bad/unwanted question in that way.

EDIT: I'm also interested in structured alternatives, community wiki or something?

Comment: Sounds like a question which is off-topic, too localized or a chameleon question...all three should be puni^H^H^H^Hbanished.

Comment: possibly I misunderstand the purpose of this Meta thing, is it described somewhere?

Comment: I'm not certain you've misunderstood, voting is different on meta, [see help pages](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Downvoting doesn't necessarily mean your post is bad, merely that people disagree with your request.

Comment: I meant the examples you've given, those sound off-topic...if you mean that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though it might annoy you I doubt very much this is a significant percentage of questions asked on Stack Overflow. There are 6.9k questions asked every day... how many deal with this particular problem?

The FAQ/help pages should cover generic points that are true for all questions or you'll get people adding special cases for the [`mysql_*` functions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143379/179419) in PHP or the proper way to ask a SQL question...

What you should do in this situation is to vote or flag to close as too localized, if appropriate. Even better, try to find a duplicate and vote or flag to close as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: The point would be to start with properly stated question, not to stomp -- just like we require doing research, submit error info, etc. If the author actually bothers to follow, discovers the answer himself, or asks an actually interesting thing, not a time-sink

Comment: I understand where you're coming from @BalogPal. I just doubt it's a big enough problem. [tag:c++] is the 7th most widely used tags. I know the regulars keep it in check very well and I know that some people in the larger tags struggle to keep up. What percentage of C++ questions have this problem? If you do this for C++ there's hundreds of other standard things out there that people continually get wrong. Should all of this also go in the FAQ?

Comment: My impression was that in the performance-related part it's way too common. You're certainly right that it is small percent in the whole bin.   FAQ was just one wild idea, now as I think of it, there's very cool helper thing launched at posting question, that shows duplicates.  Maybe that could be extended to also show text snippets on some keywords.  Reminding how to post proper question. Maybe that already exists, just need additional entries. If not, it could be used for way wider scope.