# How do I get this person to not take things personal when trying to explain how SO works?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, new-users

Apologies for the long read, but I'm a bit puzzled at a certain user's understanding.

A [newcomer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2957422/livestuff) to Stack Overflow [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051247/getting-html-from-response-stream-using-indys-idtcpclient) a few days ago. This user appears to be re-inventing the wheel - he's working on a project which someone else has already written. I pointed out that there's already a component available that comes with the environment which would make his life so much easier. Our comments in the first question were okay.

Then, this user asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062372/getting-xml-from-response-stream-using-indys-idtcpclient) yesterday on the exact same topic. We wound up having quite a lengthy and heated conversation in the comments, which wound up getting deleted. After this question was asked, I posted a comment somewhere along the lines of:

> You will find things **MUCH** easier if you were to take our recommendation and make the switch to `TIdHTTP`.

The user took this comment personal and started a big rant about

> You can recommend all you want in BOLD until you're blue in the face....

...as much as was allowed to fit in 1 comment. I replied and said not to take things personally. User kept going on and on, and in fact I had to report one of their comments. The answer made to that question was using the exact same **BOLD** which user had been offended by when I had said it. During this conversation, I had also mentioned "I can predict that you will be asking many more question on this topic." and the user started cutting down Stack Overflow and swearing up and down that I'm wrong that he will not be asking any more about it.

The user asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099780/getting-xml-string-from-response-stream-using-indys-idtcpclient) today, again on the same topic. In this question the user expressed explicitly to me that they're going ahead and making the recommended switch. In the answer by `Arioch 'The`, I asked:

> What happened to the professional that your company hired to take this project over?

(In the prior question OP stated they hired someone more experienced). User responded, not directed to me, asking if newbies are allowed to ask questions. It was obvious that they were heated that my comments weren't directly related to answering the question. So I answered and explained that Stack Overflow is not a forum, and even complimented the fact that OP has been doing a good job at asking detailed questions, except the topic they were asking about was a monster (User has 0 experience with HTTP or TCP). Nothing in my response was rude, I was simply answering the question. Again, the user posted another comment indicating they were taking things personal, and it was quite obvious that the user had something seriously against me, all because of a recommendation. User also deleted their question, so I deleted my answer, as well as another comment trying to explain that I'm trying to help them understand how the site works (still seems to think it's a forum). One of their responses is still there on the answer.

I have stopped trying to calm this person down, and honestly don't want to say another word to them until I can figure out the best way to make them stop taking every comment of mine personally. They are under the impression that I'm lurking around and only commenting to get "up-votes" and "build reputation" even though I explained twice that up-votes on comments do not affect reputation. I also asked him to take a look at the FAQ to understand how the site works (I deleted that comment, along with many others). I had tried to say everything I could to calm this person down and apologized numerous times that they seem to have a problem with me.

I don't want to completely ignore this person. I would love to help in any way possible, but I'm afraid if I say one more thing to this person that they will again fly off the handle. When I started here, I went through the same difficulty trying to understand why the rules seemed so tight. So the next time I find myself in a situation where this user needs to understand how the site works, how should/shouldn't I explain?

Comment: Whether or not it's right, my usual tactic is to help until it gets too frustrating, and then just stop replying. You can only do so much, and it's not worth losing sleep over.

Comment: PS - these 3 questions are on the exact same topic, but not necessarily duplicates. But I can tell that the user would continue asking more questions, which if I'm not mistaken is commonly referred to as a "help vampire"

Comment: 1. pfft, whatevs 2. downvote 3. latersville

Comment: Its hard to convey tone in text. No matter how you intend your comments to come off, you can't control how others will interpret it

Comment: @Won't Agreed except #2: shouldn't downvote for the attitude of the user; that doesn't reflect the question quality

Comment: @Emrakul Sometimes it does, though. But not automatically. Always.

Comment: @Andrew Sometimes, yes, but they're not dependent on each other. Downvotes reflect the question quality, which may be good regardless of the user's attitude.

Comment: I see all 3 of those questions are suddenly getting downvotes. Remember everyone, Stack Exchange monitors "serial votes".

Comment: @JerryDodge This isn't serial votes - and if it is, it'll be reversed and that's fine. This is just _the Meta Effect_ happening - asking about a question or answer draws attention to it, and that attention comes from people who may decide to vote.

Comment: Best course of action is just put down the keyboard and back away ;). I've found that anything else just causes additional frustration

Comment: @Jerry, just let that user implement his own HTTP protocol parser over the TCP communication class. That should be enough consolation price for your ego, which now wants to hear *"it was a good suggestion"* (don't take that offensively). You know that saying *"You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink"* ?

Comment: If I tried hard enough, I'm sure I could make the horse drink :P But yeah. I'm no longer frustrated, I asked this here just trying to figure out in the future how these types of situations should be handled to begin with. I mean for example, maybe there's a particular topic here on MSO which I can direct someone to so they can get a better understanding of everything, things which aren't necessarily covered in the FAQ?

Comment: This user asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152648/selecting-a-particular-node-value-in-a-xml-document Please take a look at the comments. That user edited their profile and directly harassed me, called us a bunch of f*****g nazis, and put a link to an SO hate blog.

Comment: Welp, now that linked question is deleted.

Comment: @JerryDodge yep, he deleted it himself one minute after the last comment there was posted.

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/165773)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Easy answer: Ignore the person if they're not receptive to your assistance.

People who insist on doing things incorrectly can only be helped if they're willing to accept they're wrong. If they're not, pointing it or to them will simply cause them to dig in further; instead, simply leave the person be.

That's my advice. Don't grow irritated with the person. Most of the time, other people aren't worth being upset at, about, or with. So, make a recommendation, and if the person responds negatively, let it go.

Watch out for duplicate questions, though. If you see a user ask the same question, flag a dupe. That much can be handled by the system.

Just my two cents. Or three.

Answer (score 21):

A comment from [the very first question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20051247/254830) (after you recommended TIdHTTP then asked why it wasn't implemented):

> I understand you are trying to help Jerry, but you have to understand that it is not my choice. I can't redo the component, for many reasons. Believe me, I would like to do just that, and many other things, but Im a newbee at work as much as I am here :) – LIVESTUFF

For whatever reason - constraints on time, lack of permission or something else - this guy could not necessarily take advantage of the library you were recommending and was not open to the idea of trying it out.

That's fine. Programmers get put in positions like this sometimes. We wish we could make things be better in general, but for whatever reason, we can't rewrite stuff. Sometimes, bureaucracy might even put limitations on our usage of libraries.

Much like Emrakul's suggestion, the thing to do here would have been to accept that someone is unreceptive to this particular kind of assistance, let it go and leave them alone. In this case, it seems most likely they simply *could not* take your recommendation.

However... you continued to press on him that things would be much better if only he did this thing he could not or was not willing to do. It's even possible that from his perspective, you were now following him around throwing this library at him.

*Who wouldn't* feel harassed by that?

The bottom line is:

- Don't keep offering the same assistance people are declining. Don't make them decline you over and over. They get it. You should too.
- Don't press on people to use libraries or approaches they've declined to use. Don't remind them that they "will find things so much easier," if only they did that thing you keep telling them to do - *maybe it would, but they can't use it!*

If they decline to use that library and it *would* make things easier for them, that's their problem, but it's not yours, and you're not in their situation.

Comment: For the record, 1) I only said a total of 3 mentions to this other component, all other comments were trying to teach them how SO works and to calm them down, and 2) It's actually another component from within the same library they were already using, not a different library.

Comment: Although I kind of agree with you, I think *future* visitors with similar questions should also be considered. I think it would be perfectly acceptable to write an answer saying something to the effect of "I understand you may have such and such constraints, but I highly recommend using tool X, and here's how to do it that way." If the OP doesn't like the answer, they can wait for others; the answer will still be helpful to other visitors who may not have the same constraints.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Bringing a technology up - even answering with it - is certainly completely appropriate! This answer of mine is _exclusively_ related to behaviour in comments.

Comment: @JerryDodge That changes things a bit, but the guidance here is the same. If you think TIdHTTP would be great, provide an answer _showing them_ how it will help them: that will be helpful for future visitors (as Suit points out) and give the asker something palpable to reflect on. Just reminding them in comments that it exists is not helpful. Unfortunately, since the comments on that second question are deleted, I can't see how either of you conducted yourselves - I only have your highly emotive account of matters.

Comment: The other person who answered the first question already mentioned the same thing I was, and even used the term "obviously" (which I actually hate that word). That user is also one of the well-known developers who built the said library (Indy) which is actually a well-known library which ships with Delphi.

Comment: @JerryDodge That's great that someone mentioned it then.

Comment: (or specifically, answered with it :D)

Comment: Yeah, actually Remy's answer was originally exactly my recommendation, with the code. Then when the OP commented that they cannot make that change, Remy added the other portion to his answer. Not sure why all the comments were flushed out of that answer though.

Comment: @JerryDodge Comments are transient second-class citizens that could be deleted at any time. Discussion _should not_ occur in comments on non-meta sites: they exist to request clarification or point out errors, and very little else. Stack Overflow just happens to enforce comment deletion less than other SE sites, mainly due to the unmanageable volume. Comments will generally be deleted en masse once they get disruptive or become obsolete.

Comment: I like this answer. It looks into the specific comments much more so; points out something I hadn't seen.

Answer (score -3):

If someone takes it personally,  but you have no way of knowing, would that be better? If so, just down-vote or vote to close the question, rather than leave a comment.

Comment: This isn't what downvoting and close votes are for. Close votes are for bad questions, and downvotes are for low quality questions. Neither gauges the intent or the amicability of the OP, and should not be used for retribution as such.