# What to do when user doesn't know how to use site?

Tags: support, new-users

Recently, I met a user who didn't really know how to use the Stack Exchange sites. He insisted that reputation should not exist because it's useless. How should I respond? Should I flag for a mod to help the user, or should I try to resolve it with them?

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/224576/108497) is the answer with the comments, if you want to know.

Comment: I'd just disengage in the conversation after a while - if it looks like the user's not going to listen, forget about him! If he starts posting rude comments, flag them.

Comment: Two very related discussions: [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14029/is-there-some-way-to-better-explain-the-operation-of-overflow-to-new-users), [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208280/how-do-i-get-this-person-to-not-take-things-personal-when-trying-to-explain-how) - neither really a dupe though. As you see, this issue is as old as Stack Overflow itself. :)

Comment: Sorry, the comments were cleaned up by mods

Comment: @UniKitty - you should have seen the comments that came after I deleted the comments and explained that comments should not be used for extended discussion... I had to keep deleting comments till the user got the hint.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most new users don't know how to use the sites.

They either learn or don't.

If they don't learn, they will end up in suspension.

What should you do? Once you pointed out and directed them to how things work, disengage.

If the user starts being rude, flag them.

---

Don't forget - users in highly emotional state (or trolls - sometimes it is difficult to tell the difference) will respond to comments. One can end up getting emotionally involved as well (not a good place to get to).

But - do you know what completley dampens the responses of such users? Talking to a wall. When no one engages with them, there is nothing more to inflame them (or entertain them, in the case of trolls) and they lose interest. That's a win-win.

Comment: "they will end up in suspension" - or automatic post banned, isn't it? Sometimes they just keep posting crap without being rude.

Comment: @Sha - they will get warnings before getting banned, but yes, if they keep posting low quality, they will end up in a ban.

Comment: In my experience, the consistently borderline low-quality posters don't get noticed on the lower traffic sites because there just aren't enough voters.

Comment: @Dom - that's why one should flag. Even on lower traffic sites moderators should end up noticing a pattern by a specific user.

Comment: All it does is make a mods life harder. If they decline my flag and I feel it's incorrect I have to publicly address it on meta, which just causes confrontation. If they agree they may be confronted by the person who posted the answer. There isn't much upside to it, so it's much easier just to leave it. Tangential to that, what happens if a person spreads their low quality posts across multiple accounts? It's much harder to catch and deal with for one thing.

Answer (score 7):

Be nice.

Once we were all new here, and we didn't know how things worked. If I look back to what I did back then, I can tell I was very inexperienced.

I got the time to get used to it, and we should help others out to do the same. Of course, not everyone is open to it, and you seemed to have done a nice job.

When someone is rude or just not listening, don't wast your time. Just disengage, leave the discussion. Maybe OP will learn from it. If not, he will eventually get suspended or post banned. Nothing we can do about it.