# On frustration provoked by questions where the answer is "that's not possible"

Tags: discussion, questions, user-experience

I recently had my first really bad experience on Stack Overflow. It started right after I filed a question on *[Passing a table expression to a table-parameterized function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172006/passing-a-table-expression-to-a-table-parameterized-function)* (regarding [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)). The question is since edited a bit, but not substantially.

One user spent about an hour on the question and we both got increasingly frustrated in the process. His answer got longer and longer and he remarked a number of things, some of them helpful in some regard, but he never explicitly answered my question, which was: *How to pass a table expression to a table-parameterized function*.

The guy got more and more irritated and finally asked me to unaccept the answer so he could delete it. I complied after which he deleted it.

I then posted an answer myself posting the gist of what I took away, namely that it's not possible to call table-parameterized function on arbitrary table expressions in SQL Server. This triggered two things: The guy I had a problem with got *really* angry and another person voted to delete the answer - eventually the answer got and is now deleted.

I myself eventually posted two undiplomatic comments in total at the end of it all, to each of the individuals, one of which is still on the deleted answer. I'm venturing to guess two explanations for what happened here:

#### Problem questions vs. specific questions

[On how to asked a good question the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) uses the word *problem* quite a lot. It seems to imply that a question represents a problem, a good answer for which would be anything that helps the asker.

There's another kind of question though, and that's where you really just ask a specific question. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) has 661 upvotes as of now and doesn't represent any problem. In fact, the asker, Jon Skeet, didn't have any: He just wanted to provide a good question answer pair to improve the content of this site. (EDIT: A better example is probably [this question I posted myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482581/vs2012-xaml-designer-where-is-the-resource-view). The answer will be that it's not there, even though no-one posted it yet.)

While I understand that *problem questions* are in practice often asked and certainly shouldn't be discouraged, I don't see why they should be *encouraged* at the expense of *specific questions*. Clearly for someone searching Stack Overflow the latter is more useful: If a user clicks on a question titled *Passing a table expression to a table-parameterized function* it would be better if the answer contains only the answer to that specific question first and foremost, and not an essay about how to avoid doing that.

I understand that more information can never be a bad thing (if ordered by relevance), but I don't agree that it would be more valuable than the answer to the actual, specific question, and I certainly don't agree that any *actual* answer to the specific question should get deleted just because the essay on how to avoid to ask it to begin with is missing.

#### The technology-ego-link

It's a thing that most people in the industry understand, but few ever articulate that experts identify with their technology. I have certainly seen this in myself and over the years I have come to explain a lot of what people do with how their ego is linked into this.

Let's say someone comes along and asks how to do a non-local jump across stack frames in C#. He know it's possible in C. Then people ask him why he wants to do this. Maybe they do this because they are altruists with a genuine motivation to help him, but when people dance around an answer and even get angry after I spell it out myself, I'm cynical enough to believe that often enough they feel that their technology somehow has to compete with C and the actual, correct answer (that is, "sorry, you can't") feels like a defeat. If so, such people will feel an urge to make the question look invalid or stupid in order to deflect from such perceived weakness.

It's difficult to tell these things apart, because often a programmer may indeed try something stupid - maybe jumping across stack frames has no business in his end-user application.

It's also possible, however, that the asker is just curious, doesn't really have a concrete problem at all and just wants to know. It's also possible that his curiosity was triggered by an actual problem, but now he wants to know *regardless of what the solution to his problem will be in the end*.

I feel very strongly that this is a perfectly legitimate way of asking questions. In fact my whole competence is based on this approach of wanting to actually understand what is and isn't possible rather than just letting other people suggest a path and then walking it.

I feel that I asked a legitimate question, provided a legitimate answer myself (albeit maybe not an excellent one, and I'm not sure if it's correct - but that's not the reason why it was closed) - and still got a lot of heat for it, as well as three close votes on the question and my answer deleted.

Since this is, as I said in the beginning, the first bad experience I ever had on Stack Overflow in the two years I been here, I wanted to put this story out for discussion, and I welcome any feedback.

Finally, some further notes about the edit history of my question. None of the edits changed the question, in particular the non-trivial part of the function's definition was marked with "-- The definition is not really important to this question!" from the start and changing that definition was one part of the changes. The other was replacing a generic placeholder literal "some-expression" (to make the question more clear) with an actual expression in response to another request by the first answerer.

Comment: I'm going to wait to digest most of this before commenting on most of this, but using a 5 year old question (asked when times were very very different) as the basis for why you think non-problem questions are good is not a good comparison.  Rules have changed, and some older questions are preserved for historical value.

Comment: I only skimmed the question, but I noticed that you had radically changed what you asked, which may have led to others deleting their answers.  I'll look at it a bit deeper in detail later.

Comment: I don't have the rep to see all the context, and I only read the first five paragraphs of this post, but it sounds like you accepted an answer and then debated it with the answerer ad nauseam via comments. That does sound annoying. If I were you, I simply wouldn't have accepted an answer I didn't agree with rather than arguing about it. And if I were he, I would have started ignoring you after a couple of exchanges.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I see. Do you think that question I linked is bad according to today's standards of SO? Has this been discussed on meta? (I'm asking because I personally don't see anything wrong with it according to my own standards.)

Comment: @John The Skeet "question" you linked to was a Community Wiki from inception. It is not to be taken as an example of how to ask a question for help. It was provided by Skeet as a resource to the community.

Comment: @A.Webb No. I upvoted and accepted the answer only after he implicitly argued that such a call I was trying to do wasn't possible, which I deemed the answer of my question. His answer then in effect represented an actual answer (even though terribly long-winded) and I upvoted and accepted, admittedly also in part to make up for his frustration. Until then I only upvoted one of his comments which was useful, but not an answer to my question.

Comment: @John asked today, it might survive, but would never get 600+ upvotes.  Part of the voting is based on who the asker is and part is the time when asked.  Is it a useful question? Absolutely, but not all useful questions have a home on SO (same reason we don't accept tool recommendation questions - they can be useful but they just aren't welcome for various reasons).  That being said, I was more just pointing it out.  I see no problem asking a good hypothetical question as long as there is a legitimate "problem".

Comment: Your "ego" bit seems completely off to me. When people ask "Why are you trying to do that?" for that sort of question, it's because the languages involved use different idioms - what's important isn't what the idiom does in the original language, it's what bigger purpose was being served. Without that information, we can't help provide the appropriate idiom for the same bigger problem in the other language.

Comment: @JonSkeet Off in this particular case or off in general? I would really like to know if you think the phenomenon doesn't exist even though i can completely understand you think it might to apply in this situation (it's always speculative in any concrete example).

Comment: @John: I believe it happens occasionally, but the vast majority of the time I see the "what are you trying to achieve?" question asked, it's in order to help.

Comment: @JonSkeet Put this way I agree, and I put a clarification in my question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I understand. My motivation is to not piss anyone off further by changing the text they replied to without making it obvious that I did - someone might take offence as their comment might look inappropriate when operating under the impression that the modified question was the original one.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ok, I re-edited the question.

Comment: @john now that yiu cleaned it up, I am going to delete the relavant comments, they aren't relavant to the topic at hand and distract.  I suggest you do the same with your comments.

Comment: I personally see nothing wrong with the original question on SO, and actually have an answer for it. Working on getting it taken off hold.

Comment: I think this raises an interesting question though. When a user defaces his question by removing the contents it is usually reversed if the original content was a good question. Should the same happen for answers? The answer in question seems to be very detailed and thus a good answer.

Comment: John, I edited your title to try to be more descriptive and specific about your thoughts. I'm not sure it's quite right, and if you don't like it, of course feel free to change it or roll it back. "My first bad experience" isn't a great title for this, though -- I clicked expecting to see a rant about close votes and fascist high-rep SO users that I needed to vote to close, not a thoughtful and well-written piece of reflection on asker and answerer relations.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think that's a good title.

Comment: Great, glad it works for you.

Comment: @rossipedia Thank you for you effort.

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer

Comment: Having been witness to the interaction, this started OK and deteriorated as the OP shifted requirements and continually pushed back. This went from a Q&A site to a customer service demand and, for all the things SO is, it's not getsatisfaction.com.

Comment: A couple of things: (1) Be very careful about presuming who down-votes your post. These things are anonymous for a reason, and stating that you know or think you know who it was serves no purpose. (2) I asked you to delete my answer so I could "get out" of the conversation. I don't know how you could presume that I "got *really* angry" after you posted your answer, which happened after I deleted my answer, and after I stopped interacting, period. (3) [Better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21172198/61305)?

Comment: @Aaron I think one of the reasons that they thought you got mad is that you basically self-vandalized your answer to "I've explained it, you don't get it, I'm frustrated." (Kind of bad paraphrasing, but still.) [This is the rev I'm talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21172198/6).

Comment: @hichris123 His answer appeared two minutes *after* that revision. I'm not contesting whether I was frustrated, only whether the answer made me even more so. (No, it did not. I had left by then.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't have the context, as I'm not a 10Ker, so I didn't realize that. I understand now.

Comment: Related to @AaronBertrand deleting his answer - the [right to leave](http://meatballwiki.org/wiki/RightToLeave) (from Meatball Wiki) a conversation is a *very* important one.  StackExchange offers very limited ability to get out of a conversation that someone keeps commenting on - especially if its your own answer.

Comment: Also extremely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: @AaronBertrand (1) If you didn't I regret having mentioned it, but I have no means to check that. (2) That however I know to be untrue. After you deleted your answer, I filed mine. After I filed mine, you posted a comment accusing me of having no appreciating your effort. You posted two comments in total after I posted my answer and deleted both shortly after. (3) Have a look at rossipedia's answer. It answers the question without any unnecessary distractions.

Comment: @John "unnecessary distractions" indeed. I was trying to help you solve the problem you seemed to be trying to solve, not answer a yes/no question. Sorry for trying to help, and thanks for the un-upvote.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I stayed professional until after I thought you left the conversation and I posted my own answer. When you came back only to complain you've crossed the line. Since then I had to put in hours of work to get my answer undeleted, which I didn't, and then get my question undeleted, which it now is. I now have to live with accusations by Makato, swasheck and especially Shog9 insinuating that I changed the question like some noob who asked you to do my homework. My capacity to sympathize is exhausted for now and living without your help in the future will work best for both of us.

Comment: Don't worry, I was already planning on not answering any more of your question thanks to the amount of work *I* have put into this. Remember that you came to this site for help, don't try to make people who tried to help you feel guilty for doing so.

Comment: Can someone TL;DR this? I can't understand if OP is upset that I deleted his non-answer?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I was, and I still can't see why my answer wasn't at least acceptable unless something better came along as it answered directly the question that was asked. It doesn't matter anymore though because someone else posted an answer that I've accepted since.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Another patronizing remark from you. Let me return the favor: *Remember that you have to get along with people, and when you talk down to them multiple times they might eventually give something back.* See what I did there? You're not my daddy and I didn't come to you for help. I posted a public question in the same spirit that I post answers on SO. Even though I don't spend as much time here as you do I can and did provide valuable content. There is no reason for me to tolerate your condescension.

Comment: @John I wasn't scolding you, patronizing you or being condescending. Just reminding you that you came here for help (and that your behavior can, and in this case did, cause you to get less help from some people in the future).

Comment: @John: about your (deleted) answer. As it was phrased, I would expect many people to vote for its deletion as "not an answer". It may appear to be an answer ("No, you can't do that") but it's only based on hear-say from someone else and not on your knowledge, experience or other references.

Comment: @ypercube +1 And that's a reason that makes sense to me. I should have put it in a comment on the question.

Comment: [Interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482581/vs2012-xaml-designer-where-is-the-resource-view#comment20681994_14755712): `Marking this as the answer as the respective functionality is probably simply not in Visual Studio itself, and this is the best plan b so far.` Why didn't you ask him "Why didn't you just say it's not there?" and give him some crap for trying to be too helpful?

Comment: @AaronBertrand For the same reason I didn't give you any crap and accepted and upvoted your answer before you deleted it and started to give *me* crap. Remember?

Comment: @John you remember it however you like. I'm telling you how I felt about the overall experience.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Just saw that you were among the ones to close-vote my *question*... but you may still not be a liar formally: After all, you just claimed that I should be "very careful about presuming who down-votes your post". You should be ashamed of yourself.

Comment: @John Are you saying that down-voting and voting to close are the same thing? If so, *you* should be ashamed of yourself for not bothering to do any research whatsoever and understand how this site works. They are different things for a reason. Four people down-voted your question, and five people voted to close it. I answered. It didn't get re-opened until you brought your complaints here (and I still don't think it should have been re-opened). How much energy are you going to spend trying to accuse me of being one of the down-voters? What do you think you're accomplishing?

Comment: When did I deny ***voting to close*** your question? I did no such thing. And if you look closely at what I said about presuming who ***down-voted*** - which is a very different thing - even if I had down-voted, what about what I said denied that I down-voted? Pretty sensible advice in either case - don't go accusing people of who down-voted what, because there is no possible way for you to know, and it accomplishes absolutely nothing.

Comment: Interesting, making a lot of noise and then removing what you say. Can you stop bothering me now? What provoked [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216682/on-frustration-provoked-by-questions-where-the-answer-is-thats-not-possible#comment704757_216682) SIX DAYS LATER anyway? Grow up and let it go.

Comment: On what planet does it make sense that voting to close is worse? Voting to close gives you a notification that your question needs to be improved. I absolutely did that once I realized that you were asking one thing but you really meant another. IIRC I voted to close as unclear what you're asking. This gives you an opportunity to improve, *at no cost to you*. Down-voting, on the other hand, takes rep from you, in most cases with absolutely no feedback to you on how to improve. So why on earth is voting to close worse? And why does voting to close mean that they must have also down-voted?

Comment: And again, even if I had down-voted, so what? Let's pretend I did down-vote (among, now, 5 total down-voters). When did I lie? Whether I down-voted or not, it is still absolutely non-constructive to accuse me of doing so. You'll notice I edited your question to remove it because it absolutely pointless conjecture and it has nothing at all to do with your beef. Now, can you please leave me alone so I can leave this conversation too, without getting pinged by more nonsense about whether voting to close is worse than down-voting, or why I should care that that's your opinion?

Comment: This is pure nonsense. Even if someone claims to have downvoted, you can never be sure if he is telling the truth or not. Hey @John, if 10 people say they downvoted that question of yours, will you believe them?

Comment: @ypercube I believed him when he said he didn't and I still do.

Comment: Then what has been the point of all of this conversation today? What, exactly, should I be ashamed about, and why?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Just re-read my comments *carefully*, as you should have done with my question. For a guy who repeatedly implies that I'm somehow bothering him by getting him pings to this question you are fairly obnoxiously returning to it when you just as well could have left it alone - I wasn't responding to you.

Comment: I've read them multiple times, and they're still nonsensical. Can you answer my questions straight? (1) Why did you drag me back to this questions 6 days later? (Look closely at your first comment here today, and tell me how that's not responding to me.) (2) What exactly do you think I should be ashamed of? That I voted to close your unclear question (which four others also thought was unclear)? In English, please, not allegory.

Comment: By "not responding to you" I obviously meant [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216682/on-frustration-provoked-by-questions-where-the-answer-is-thats-not-possible#comment704820_216682) - but I think you know that: You just choose to ignore it, because your comments might be addressed to me, but they are really made for your cheerleaders. I've said what I wanted to add [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216682/on-frustration-provoked-by-questions-where-the-answer-is-thats-not-possible#comment704789_216682), and I'll leave it at that. Please leave me alone now.

Comment: Okay, so you can provoke me into a discussion, make multiple accusations you can't prove, and then end the discussion when you want? Sounds mature to me, if we were 12.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'That's not possible" is a completely legitimate answer to a sufficiently specific question. If a person asks a question of fact ("Does Java have a native complex number data type?"), it is completely reasonable to politely answer no, without encrusting that 'no' with a load of verbiage about libraries, or classes, or Kronecker/Brouwer rants that there are no such things as complex numbers. The idea that answers must somehow guess what problem the OP 'really' means to solve and offer an alternative is unreasonable.

If the question is phrased to request solutions to an actual functional problem and only mention some specific yes-or-no question in passing, then 'no' is indeed unresponsive. But when the question is a straight-up yes-or-no question, with no text asking for 'in the event of 'no', please offer alternative solutions to actual problem Y', then the answer if, no, is no.

Answer (score 19):

In your dissertation on "Problem questions vs. specific questions" you are missing one very key point.  Specific questions are problem questions.  You have a question on how to perform a specific task (and if it is even possible).  That is a "problem", so let's throw that entire argument out the window.  You had a question and asked an on-topic question, end of story.

And I don't see anything in particular wrong with your specific question, either.  I not an SQL guy, but seems to be a legitimate question and your examples seem to fit well with the question.  I think your decision to edit it from generic examples to a more specific one was also a good decision.  Probably not necessary to actually answer the question, but makes it easier to understand what you are asking for a novice who finds your question and is interested in the answers.

As for the issue with the answer/answerer and the deleted answers (including your own).  I think you are trying to read too much into it.  Without 10K on SO, I have zero context, so I am basing this solely on your description of events, so if something might have any observational bias, not my fault for misrepresenting the facts.

First for your answer.  Based on the context of your replacement answer provided by [Martin Smith](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216682/on-frustration-provoked-by-questions-where-the-answer-is-thats-not-possible#comment701759_216686):

> According to @ABC, with whom I had a contorted exchange, this isn't possible. Table-to-table expressions cannot be factored out in functions in SQL Server. If anyone thinks this is wrong, please provide another answer.

This is absolutely not an answer and deserved to be deleted, which it was.  It does not appear to even have been deleted by the individual you had the conversation with, but actually appears to have been in response to a flag from another user and deleted by a moderator.

I think the core of it is you ended up with an hour long discussion on an answer with a specific user and you pissed him off or annoyed him enough that he wanted to be rid of the question, so deleted his answer.  In the end, if the answer is "No it is not possible", then poking and prodding the user to provide more info is probably not going to amount to much more other than annoying the user.  A long continuous discussion on questions and answers is generally not well received by most users and you should avoid doing it.  You are usually best off waiting for another answer that might have a different thought.

If you have new questions that come from answers to your own questions, that can't be answered by a quick follow up comment, you are usually best researching the new problem and then asking a new question.

Comment: I *did* credit the guy in my answer, along with saying that I had a "contorted exchange" with him. Maybe it was the word "contorted" (even though I didn't blame any one of us), but I think I would have evoked less ire if I didn't credit him.

Comment: @John ok, I took that part out, but added an alternative.  Ultimately, you pissed off someone and they had a problem with you.  Not much else to say without those users jumping into the discussion here.

Comment: The answer was actually deleted by two votes. A trusted user and a moderator.  I presume it was flagged a Not an Answer. The entire content of the deleted answer was `According to @ABC, with whom I had a contorted exchange, this isn't possible.

Table-to-table expressions cannot be factored out in functions in SQL Server.

If anyone thinks this is wrong, please provide another answer.`

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for the info.  I have updated the answer to better reflect what happened.

Answer (score 13):

Let me explain why I was frustrated.

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21172006/1) was (paraphrased):

> I have this function. <code> I'm struggling to call it. I tried this syntax (<code> and <pseudo-code>), but SQL Server "didn't like it." Is this possible? If so, what is the syntax for it?

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21172198/61305) - which you up-voted and accepted - attempted to explain the various things that were wrong with your function, as well as pointing out better ways to accomplish what I thought you were trying to accomplish (and what I still think you are trying to accomplish, and I'd be extremely surprised if you don't end up using something very much or exactly like something in my answer). You argued with me for about an hour about whether SQL Server is capable of doing what you want to do (which, looking back, I failed to comprehend.) At some point in that period you updated the question to show what you were actually trying to do - pass a query by reference. Which is not possible, and which I immediately told you so, once I realized - by virtue of you having finally included real code in your question - that's what you were trying to do. I promptly got "well, why didn't you just say that?" After an hour of going back and forth trying to figure out what you were trying to get, and discovering that all you wanted was a yes or no answer, I was absolutely frustrated - and you would have been too. As pointed out before, one of the only ways you can get out of a conversation here is to delete the post being discussed, so that's what I did, because I felt that nothing further could be accomplished going any more rounds with you about whether my answer actually answered your question.

Generally, people don't come to Stack Overflow for yes/no answers, and most of those that do see their answers swiftly closed (since a yes/no answer is arguably not very useful for future readers). Was this more acceptable at one time? Sure. But it's not anymore, as *several* people here have already told you. Most people come to Stack Overflow to get a solution. And in good faith that's what I thought I offered. If I knew you only wanted to know if it was possible (and had actually included enough code in the question to know immediately that it was not), I would have left a comment instead of bothering to write a more elaborate answer aimed at guiding you to a solution.

In the future, I strongly recommend that if you only want a yes/no answer, and aren't going to find any other commentary useful, you state so explicitly up front. And don't include things like `<some expression>` because that makes it even less clear what you're even asking about. In fact I recommend you go back and edit your question so that it only asks whether or not you can pass a query by reference to a function in SQL Server. That's a one-sentence question to which a yes/no answer would be much more appropriate than the current form of the question - which seems to be begging for alternative solutions, not just confirmation one way or the other.

Comment: +1 for being constructive. It wasn't a *yes/no* question but a *no or yes and if yes, how* question. The answer is trivial only in the *no* case. Questions of this sort should be rather typical. - I don't want to make it a one-liner because I've seen the ire those produce. (No effort!) - As for "pass a query by reference": That might be clearer to you, but I find this phrase to be nonsensical. If you said pass the *table* by reference or value, that would still be a weird way of putting it, but it would evoke the right kind of idea. That's why I used the term *table expression* in the subject.

Comment: @John no, that's the opposite way to think about it. You wanted to pass the query semantics (the query) into the function, not the results of the query (the table).

Comment: Since a query is always an abstraction and doesn't actually contain the results it can deliver, *copying* a query can't be much different from *copying a reference to* a query. If you had a `struct` in C# or a class with value semantics in C++ that represents a query in some potential database framework, copying that value type isn't going to copy a table unless the designer of that library had a *very* strange attitude. And that's about the only criteria I would know to go by to judge if the phrasing you propose makes sense in this context: SQL itself doesn't use terms such as *by reference*.

Comment: @John *shrug* I don't know what to tell you buddy. That the phrase I chose to use doesn't make sense to you is no more my fault than the fact that I misinterpreted the intention of your question. I'm telling you what it sounded like you were trying to do *in my words.* I don't really care if that's not how you would describe it - pick another phrase then. Something you didn't do originally, which is why I had to come up with my own words in the first place. I started in VB, not C++ or C#, so describing it the way I did makes absolute sense to me (and probably anyone else familiar with VB).

Comment: "I don't really care if that's not how you would describe it - pick another phrase then." And there we go again. Why would I have to comply with your demands this time? I'm perfectly in my rights to leave the question phrased as it is, understood by some other guy who posted the answer I since accepted. I will leave this conversation now.

Comment: @John you don't have to do anything, and you don't have to use the phrase I suggested. Again, it is just a suggestion. My point stands that your question seems to be ***asking for solutions*** not ***asking for a yes/no answer***. Get it yet?

Comment: Yes, I get it. You keep trying to frame yourself as the big, helpful guy who didn't needlessly attack me and got offensive, but simply makes constructive suggestions that silly me refuses to hear. Everyone is free to look at http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21172198/6 to see a bit of rudeness that came at the point where I was still perfectly polite to see why you shouldn't succeed in doing that. Most of your snide remarks you've since deleted. - Someone else understood the question, so maybe it's just you? How about you just answer questions you understand? That's how I go about it.

Comment: @John I didn't delete those comments, I suspect a moderator did. Was I rude? Absolutely! You frustrated the crap out of me, especially when - after putting significant effort into an answer - you said "why didn't you just say no?" Also, there is a pretty big difference between not understanding a question and mistaking what a question means because it is ambiguous or misleading. I'm clearly not the only one who expects - in your case specifically, and on SO in general - that a question like that is seeking solutions or workarounds, not a one-word answer.

Comment: I believe you and apologize for claiming that you deleted your comments yourself.