# What do you do when someone is using the wrong tool?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm just going to pick on one question, only because I just saw it.  This is not necessarily the **best** example, but it's an example:

[Using VBA in Excel to copy a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023608/using-vba-excel-search-and-copy-the-entire-row-to-another-sheet-one-after-other)

The scenario is; what do you do when you see someone trying to put a square peg in a round hole?  In other words, this person is using Excel when they should probably be using Access.

Would you ignore it?  Try to answer their question as-is?  Suggest a better tool?

Comment: Related: [Is "don't do it" a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's actually possible to insert the square peg and you know how to do so, I think you should explain that process and then supplement your answer with your thoughts on why they shouldn't be using a square peg in the first place ("this trick only works if the peg is much smaller than the hole", "square pegs are deprecated", etc.). Then give an example of an alternate solution ("starting with Holes 2.0, you can create round pegs"). Pointing out the differences between the two solutions can go a long way to selling the questioner on round pegs.

You're kind of answering the question twice but I think this approach is more useful (particularly when another user in the exact same situation comes searching for answers).

Answer (score 8):

Post a comment.  What you have is information that you feel is helpful but that is not answering the question.  The proper way to provide that is through comments.  It's not an answer because it is specifically violating constraints in the question itself.  It can often seem odd to you, but in many situations there really are reasons for odd constraints in questions, and explaining their reasoning isn't always productive.

If the user generalizes the question a bit (possibly at your request) to remove the constraint of the tool you disagree with, then you may have an actual answer on your hand that answers the question.

If there really is an important reason for the given constraint, then the author may expand on why the given constraint is in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I tend to leave a comment asking *why* they chose this tool, to try and understand whether there is any particular reason to do so or if this is just a case of the XY problem. I will also give them a link to this:

[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

If the OP has valid reasons to use the approach they're using, I go with it, if not I will post an answer offering a better alternative. Such cases are usually eventually accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Suggesting a better tool may be the right thing to do, but understanding that people frequently find themselves in work group situations that dictate a tool choice.  Suggesting a different tool isn't helpful in that case.  So, best to offer a suggestion (if nothing else to guide other readers) and also query the poster in a comment about whether they have the flexibility to change tools; their answer may guide your answer.