# Answer or Comment when the answer to a question is "not possible"?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

Sometimes the answer to a question is "that isn't supported" or "not possible." In those cases is it more appropriate to say this as a *comment* or as an *answer*?

See for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491099/view-tags-of-a-docker-image-from-index-docker-io/22493089#22493089). I answered the question, others left comments basically saying the same thing. Which is the right thing to do, for my future reference?

Comment: "Not possible" is a totally valid answer provided that you give some explanation.

Comment: So it should be an answer, not a comment?

Comment: See also: ["Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, your answer, while valid, should be a comment. As a general rule of thumb, I feel that any answer that starts with "AFAIK" is more appropriate as a comment.

Changes that could be made to justify it as an actual answer include:

- References to a source that says explicitly why it is not possible and/or an explanation of why it is not possible.
- References to documentation (with explanation) of the API version in question that can be used to concretely prove that it is not in fact possible.
- Information (e.g. bug reports, feature requests, mailing list discussions) that talks about the potential of it becoming possible in the future.
- Alternate approaches.

"AFAIK this is not possible", even if your instincts and knowledge *are* correct, isn't necessarily evidence of correctness. In the bigger picture, consider this: What if there *is* a way to do this, but you didn't happen to know what it was ("AFAIK")? What if, then, another person with the same question found your answer in the future and took it as concrete fact? What if it got even worse, and they wrote an unnecessary workaround in a blog somewhere that others found? That's not to say your answer isn't necessarily correct, but we should strive to give answers that are as definitive possible.

Comment: Great answer. In reviewing my answer I also just noticed what the question was asking is, in fact, possible as of today. So I've updated my answer. :)