# Why upvote answers that propose a better way to do the task rather than answering the question?

Tags: discussion

I see this all time, especially when it comes to coding answers.  Someone will post their code and tell what they are trying to do for context.  They will ask about how to go about a certain step in their existing code.  An answerer will ignore the person's question, and instead provide an entirely different way to accomplish the task the user is trying to accomplish.

Here's a simplified example: 
Q: I'm using python and I want to add up all the even numbers in a list. Here's my code:

```
for num in numbers:
    if even:
       total+=num
```

How do I find out even?

A: There is this thing called list comprehensions blah blah blah....

then the answerer proceeds to show how list comprehensions work, instead of answering how to determine if a number is even.

Why do answers that provide entirely different code from the questioner's instead of addressing the specific question that was asked not get downvoted to oblivion?  Shouldn't the answer come first instead of an uninvited code critique?  Or are there valid reasons for taking this approach I have outlined?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to quite match the behavior your talking about. You seem to be asking about people proposing alternate solutions to the overall problem, but your example has the hypothetical answerer answering a different question that is only superficially related. Because of that, it's hard to tell what exactly you are asking about.

Comment: If you're looking for an example [here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15060529/119477). The accepted answer got one vote. The answer that wants the OP to redesign their tables got 6 votes. I found it by searching for `[sql] "should normalize"`

Comment: Instead of voting on how closely the answer matches the stated question, you could deliberately ask questions in such a way as to make it clear you are agnostic about the solution method.

Comment: I... I... I'm sorry, irony called and I did my best to answer.

Answer (score 10):

Because sometimes "Don't do that" [can be a better answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer). If an answerer believes the user is going in the wrong direction, letting them know that can be of value, rather than blindly answering the letter of the question.

Answer (score 5):

Votes are there to indicate whether a given post is helpful or not helpful.  Some people believe that an answer that solves the problem described by the question is more helpful than a literal answer to the question in a manor that doesn't best solve the problem that the question relates to.

You are of course free to have your own opinions on whether or not a particular answer is helpful or not, even if it conflicts with other members of the community, and can vote accordingly.

Of course the specific context is going to be relevant.  Overgeneralizing is likely to not effectively capture the community's voting patterns here.  It's important for the specific question/answer be analyzed to determine if the answer is actually helpful.  Perhaps the most helpful thing to do is not answer the question, perhaps an answer isn't helpful because it doesn't answer the question, and all sorts of little details in the context can affect whether or not an answer is actually helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think your example is probably occurring in some context, but it makes a stronger point when you can actually link that happening "in the wild" (on SO or another code based site).

As a result, I am inclined to believe that "An answerer will ignore the person's question" is not entirely accurate. However, answers are posted which do not contain the same code as the OP. When that happens it is mostly like a result of pushing best practice provided it is not drastically altering the code.

Often this different code will have an advantage, and ideally that advantage will be described in detail so that there is an understanding of the differences in the two approaches.

Code critiquing is going to happen any time something which has been done many times over is being done either incorrectly or inefficiently. As most of the people who critique have probably been through the same learning curve, they are just trying to improve code quality and are not out to cause offense.

I think there are valid reasons to offer an alteration of code if it solves the problem raised in the question. However, if an answerer is completely ignoring the question, then it should be flagged accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than answer your question, I'm going to propose that you visit [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), where we routinely recommend alternate solutions, even if the question's author did not ask for it:

> […]
>   6. Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?
>
> If you answered yes to all the above questions, your question is on-topic for Code Review.