# How to ask questions in a way that avoids answers that question/patronize the approach rather than address the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, asking-questions

Sometimes I or others ask a question which causes the reader to think *why would he want to do that?*. There are reasons and the question is usually legitimate. I and others often seem to get a lot of comments (which I don’t mind), and comments posted as answers (which I do mind), which do not even attempt to address the question and instead question the approach and provide zero insight on the actual question.

I am talking about the kind of question where the question is usually a few sentences, but a solid explanation of why the approach that leads to the question is chosen takes almost a full page of writing, and is irrelevant to the question itself. The issue seems to be well understood and there are various related questions on Meta, such as:

- [Why upvote answers that propose a better way to do the task rather than answering the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235202/249029)
- [Should there be a way to differentiate answers that directly address the question vs. providing a better way to solve the problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56938/249029)
- [Answering a Question Vs. Solving a Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17627/249029)

My question is not why this happens. My question is how can I formulate a question in such a way that this happens less.

**To be clear, I am asking *What can a question do to avoid getting answers that do not address the question?*, in the context of well-meaning answerers who try to see an underlying cause.**

Two questions with different approaches which should show what I mean:

- [What are the consequences of revoking a credit card charge made to Origin?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201126/99134) (note that the question is off-topic but it still serves to illustrate the type of questions and answers I mean)
- [UK hotel overcharged credit card, where to complain?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43519/23099)

Comment: That’s a question I wanted to ask a long time ago but never came around to do it, as I feel to suffer from the same problem. I suggest to term this the *YX problem* (in analogy to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/255554)). Some example questions of mine: [1](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/6616/1822), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24776715/2127008), [3](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17145/7734).

Comment: Also, I must resist to the urge to post an answer to this along the lines of *Why would you want to do that? Those people are trying to help you and solve your actual problem.* just for being meta.

Comment: [Why do people question every question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108060/why-do-people-question-every-question)

Answer (score 4):

There's ultimately nothing you can do that will *guarantee* that the answers you get won't question your question.

You can *reduce* the risk of getting such answers by explaining the circumstances that led you to your question, or by declaring "Yes, I know that doing X implies Y and that it would be better to do A but I can't do A because B."

The two examples you give are problematic:

- The [first one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201126/99134) is off-topic. The question is about a credit card transaction that happens to be a game purchase. It is not at its core a question about a game. I've witnessed on many occasion that people who answer off-topic questions do not feel particularly obliged to abide by whatever limits the off-topic question sets. In other words, the off-topicness of the question is not helping you.
- In the [second question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43519/23099), the details that led you to your situation are *in fact relevant*. You ask:

  > As a foreigner, is there an Ombudsman or some consumer association like the BBB where I can send a complaint to, or do I need to go to court? And if so, which one?

  The fact is that, despite a later disclaimer in your question, you *are* asking for legal advice ("do I need to go to court?"). Whether your case would be better handled in court, in arbitration, through your credit card company, through an ombudsman, through a consumer association, or in some other way, depends on the *specifics* of what happened.

Answer (score -1):

Just flatly list your out of spec or unusual conditions as bulleted requirements. That's what a user did in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/664676/ssh-with-dsa-2048-bits-key) and after some discussion the community provided a resolution.