# What to do when I suspect a person is asking questions to become a cracker?

Tags: discussion, users, offensive

I see a user who asked many questions and they are (almost) all about preventing or breaking user protection and blocking users out (of code or where files come from). I seriously think he is trying to learn how to crack. Worse of all, his questions seem to be wasting people's time. (If you read them you'll see what I mean). What should I do?

You guys are saying 1) it's ok, 2) show an example. So I'll post some questions:

- [How to disable or encrypt “View Source” for my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788539/how-to-disable-or-encrypt-view-source-for-my-site)
- [How to enable javascript in client machine using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803485/how-to-enable-javascript-in-client-machine-using-php)
- [Is it possible to protect from downloading a video from a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790190/is-it-possible-to-protect-from-downloading-a-video-from-a-site)

This one is somewhat suspicious:

- [Could any one explain What is FEDEX ACC # and Meter # in FEDEX Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485527/could-any-one-explain-what-is-fedex-acc-and-meter-in-fedex-integration)

These ones just made me mad:

- [.mov file to .flv file conversion issue for ffmpeg using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920753/mov-file-to-flv-file-conversion-issue-for-ffmpeg-using-php)
- [How might I improve the execution time of my join-heavy query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892328/how-might-i-improve-the-execution-time-of-my-join-heavy-query)

Comment: Can you give us an example? It's hard for us to tell, without looking at the questions...

Comment: Hacking's fun. Don't knock it until you've got the feds knocking down your door.

Comment: Programming = Hacking

Comment: There is nothing wrong with people who want to get a deeper understanding how things work. That also include breaking things. The knowledge is not harmful, indeed it could be helpful. He could do harmful things, but how do you want to figure that out? Give us examples! Keep in mind, there is no security by obscurity.

Comment: Hey, while you're at it, could you go back and accept some more of your answers on Stack Overflow? 41% is a pretty crap accept rate, really. I *know* there are at least some of your questions where (a) people have asked for more details and you haven't provided any, or (b) the highest upvoted answer languishes at the top and nobody knows whether it really solved your problem or not. Thanks for listening.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/questions-with-nefarious-intent

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call him out, and when he tries to attack you, openly tell him your IP address...

[image: There's no place like 127.0.0.1]
<sub>(source: [userfriendly.org](http://www.userfriendly.org/cartoons/archives/01may/uf003073.gif))</sub>

Comment: OK, I have no idea why this is the accepted answer ;-p

Comment: Haha - neither do I but its an awesome comic! :-)

Comment: Simple :3. I didnt like any of the answers, people urge me to increase my accept rate and everyone knows this is a joke :D

Answer (score 17):

> [How to disable or encrypt "View Source" for my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788539/how-to-disable-or-encrypt-view-source-for-my-site)

Nothing to do with hacking, really!

> [How to enable javascript in client machine using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803485/how-to-enable-javascript-in-client-machine-using-php)

Sounds more like he wants to prevent the "your browser does not support JavaScript" scenario in a very dumb way.

> [Is it possible to protect from downloading a video from a site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790190/is-it-possible-to-protect-from-downloading-a-video-from-a-site)

He wants to protect his intellectual property in way that is impossible. I see no hacking question here.

> [Could any one explain What is FEDEX ACC # and Meter # in FEDEX Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485527/could-any-one-explain-what-is-fedex-acc-and-meter-in-fedex-integration)

I would say he tries to use an API. Is that forbidden?

> [.mov file to .flv file conversion issue for ffmpeg using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920753/mov-file-to-flv-file-conversion-issue-for-ffmpeg-using-php)

Converting files is really hackish! Shame on him!`</sarcasm>`
Sorry, but what is the problem here?

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892328/how-might-i-improve-the-execution-time-of-my-join-heavy-query

Optimising queries? Jail him! How could he dare?

Honestly, what's your point, acidzombie24? This guy does not ask the smartest questions, if you ask me, but that's not a crime.

Comment: The last two is to show how poorly his questions are and how he is lazy and wants to be spoon fed. The fedex one is just suspicious. The others look like means to obscure and spam a user.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't seen spam attempts either, but I was not looking for them. Whatsoever I see no evidence that he wants to become a hacker. Neither white nor black hat or whatever in-between. Therefore I do not get the intent of your question. He does not do any hackish things. He is a bad asker, so ask him via comments to improve his questions, downvote unclear questions or leave him alone and let other deal with him.

Comment: Number two is specifically asking how to write malware, whether or not the guy realizes it.  The only reason I'd give him the benefit of the doubt is that he seems clueless, and there's lots of people out there who are trying to do something and haven't the faintest idea of the repercussions.

Answer (score 14):

I don't see the problem with answering those sorts of questions - the knowledge needed to break computer security is the same knowledge needed to prevent and protect from these attacks, and so propagating this knowledge is going to help improve computer security overall.

Answer (score 3):

Give a man a fish, and he'll eat for a day. Teach a man to fish, and he'll eat for life.

Now s/fish/hack/, and you're actually impeding his hacking progress by making him reliant on SO for every answer :P

Regardless, there is **always** a legitimate use for this knowledge, and as such the answers should exist on SOFU.