# New reason to close question: "Saving civilization"

Tags: feature-request

For questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962217/background-music-html).

Comment: Funny, but off-topic, unless the [always friday in iceland] tag is used.

Comment: Haha, but duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/questions-with-nefarious-intent

Answer (score 4):

This is a horribly mean idea that hurts worse than having something closed as being "actively harmful to the site". I mean, even in the example question you give, it is a legitimate thing to ask on SO and the question asker gives understandable reason to have such an inquiry.

If you think something is a bad idea, you can recommend against it or just ignore it altogether. But the question doesn't deserve to be closed if it is a legitimate question on the site.

Comment: It's a duplicate.  I voted to close.

Comment: @Robert did you actually look at the duplicate you voted to close as. It's got 1 answer with no actual code on how to do things.

Comment: I actually voted to close this saving-civilization question as "actively harmful to the site"...

Comment: @ear Not (yet) having answers doesn't bother me, it *could* still be a dupe.  (It's not in this case, though.)

Comment: @Earlz: People can post their answers to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

If you think this should *never* be allowed, you might want to reconsider.

Google did [background music](http://google.com/pacman/) recently, and did it appropriately.

Comment: Ah, but there was a bit of a kerfluffle over that, mostly from companies that have a corporate policy of employees not playing games during work hours. Some of them actually mandated that Google be removed as the home page temporarily. Imagine the manager walking in, and hearing the Pac-Man song emanating from all corners of the cubicles.

Comment: @Robert: Sure, it can be misused or doesn't work as well everywhere, but it was still appropriate for that game. Earlz actually convinced me (in a comment on that question) it's not a duplicate, since considerations for bg music for a game and for a static page are different.