# Comment links be greater than Question links? It's just not fair!

Tags: feature-request, questions, comments, ethics, tooltips

Look at the comment I posted below! If you hover over the link you'll see a nice title text with the title of the question. But but. With this link [link text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52253/new-reason-to-close-question-saving-civilization/) or this one: [New reason to close question: "Saving civilization"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52253/new-reason-to-close-question-saving-civilization/)  there be no title text! Why must Jeff be biased towards comments so much! Shouldn't questions get the same rights as comments?

Comment: Hover over this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52253/new-reason-to-close-question-saving-civilization/

Answer (score 2):

```
try [this][1]

[1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52253/new-reason-to-close-question-saving-civilization/  "new reason to close question, 'saving civilization'"
```

try [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52253/new-reason-to-close-question-saving-civilization/)

Comment: Yea but why can't the engine just automatically detect SO links like it does for comments and fill in the title bit for us?

Comment: As I demonstrate with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52253/ @Earlz, it only makes those titles when you have a question title cut off in the link (which happens in comments). In normal question body, the trail is not cut off, which makes it quite visible such that hovering is unnecessary.