# Is it OK to ask for malware on SO?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions with nefarious intent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/questions-with-nefarious-intent)

There is this question on SO: [Is there any malware / keylogger on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440754/is-there-any-malware-keylogger-on-linux)

He wants to have tips for existing malware or a keylogger for Linux (to test the products of his company. ??? What could not be verified!)

How to cope with this kind of questions?

I voted to close (because its offtopic) and flagged it for moderator attention (because I think its not OK). I don't think this is a deliver me my virus site.

Comment: I just gave to last vote to close the question as  *off-topic*...because it is, he's asking on how to break into a secured computer system...that's off-topic on SO. I think we need a white-hat-hacking-proposal on Area51.

Comment: @Pekka: Have the comments since been deleted?

Comment: @Andrew yup, a mod must have deleted them.

Comment: Obviously not. It belongs on Super User!

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I disagree, he's asking about system/network penetration either via software tools or social engineering. The first would belong on SF and I'm not sure if we have a site for the second.

Comment: Now the question's been deleted.