# Questions closed because they are unpopular, but on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, ethics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions with nefarious intent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/questions-with-nefarious-intent)

Every so often, we get a question like this on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452855/how-can-i-hide-my-program-from-task-manager

I realize this will probably be voted-to-close by the time you read this, probably as off-topic or "not a real question."

But is it?  I realize it's unpalatable -- there's usually not a good reason to do what the OP is asking.  But "legitimate" software does this too (think: security software, anti-virus, etc.)  So should it be closed?  It is a programming question, and it's a slippery slope to get into the judgement of intentions behind the question.  (Ok, in this case, he says it's for a keylogger, but what if he said it was for "parental control" software?)

Comment: You're seeing a first attempt or code that others aren't/can't see?

Comment: Why did you choose such a crap quality question and frame it like it was closed on the basis of ethics?

Comment: Interesting to contrast it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434976/how-to-create-keylogger-hidden-in-dll-university-scope from yesterday (and also closed). Any mods want to look at those profiles?

Comment: It's also a duplicate question many times over, but I really can't bring myself to help a keylogger-writer who can't be bothered to search.

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring the fact that it's an excessively basic question, and focusing only on the ethics -

Strictly speaking, it should not be closed or downvoted because it mentions a keylogger. It's a perfectly valid question that could apply to any kind of program, including legit ones.

However, there is a strong sentiment against assisting with the writing of malware. Questions openly discussing  malware (or appearing to do so) will be received badly.

Rewording the question will often help - for better (if it's an innocent purpose) or worse (if the OP is really writing malware).

Comment: I'd bet that if he hadn't mentioned anything about why he needed it, it'd get closed anyway for the same reason.

Comment: @Joe yeah, true - but rightly so, as I bet the answer can be Googled within a minute. Didn't think of that

Comment: There's lots of answers here you could probably just Google.  I guess I don't find the current close reasons to include ethical/moral objection, and I wonder if that's an area we should be delving into at all...

Comment: @Joe  People dislike questions they deem unethical, I don't think there is much that can (nor should) be done about that.

Comment: Dislike is fine -- vote it down, don't answer.  But I'm specifically asking about close votes: why is this question voted to close?  (Rory provides some good details below, but I think that's a nitpick -- if he provided that info, I don't think the result would be any different.)

Comment: @Joe I think it wasn't closed because of the ethics, but because it was a bad question.

Answer (score 6):

It's just not a good question - it shows no effort at all. A google will give you the answer instantly.

Additionally - you should include the version of operating system etc., as well as information around what the program is (does it run as a DLL or an exe etc)