# "Keylogger" type questions should maybe not be allowed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions, scope

I have asked a question on Stackoverflow asking for a head start on a keylogger which I specifically said in the "disclaimer" that it was for personal use on my computer only and would not be redistributed or used stupidly. Im am fully aware that asking a question for help with a keylogger isn't the best idea however this is what Stackoverflow is for and there is even a tag for it.

Seeing as people can easily find out how a key logger works on any web page but can't always find reliable code, I therefore posted it on SO where I am more likely to be provided with something reliable.

The question I asked is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984843/keylogger-tutorial) and as you can see by my downvote, its not a liked question so I therefore am asking, what is the point in having a tag for "keylogger" and should this type of question not be permitted on SO?

Please bare in mind I am not asking this because I have downvotes as I will accept them, I am asking as it obviously isnt an accepted sort of question on SO.

Comment: You can always ask *how* things work, but creating things that have the potential to do harm is a bit...tricky.

Comment: It's not specifically the topic (though that may have had a bit to do with it) - Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial repository is all. It's for specific questions.

Comment: I voted it down because it seems rather malicious to make it run in 'stealth mode'. If you're just doing it for yourself, then remove that from the question.  You can always ask, "How do any processes run in stealth mode." to have that question answered. But apart from that, it is a rather poor question, almost like a "find a tutorial for me."

Comment: question improvement pointers would have also been nice, rather than simple downvotes and requests to delete it as I was and still am under the impression it's due to my question topic

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with questions of nefarious intent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent) You may also find [Pekka's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115531/148672) to one of its dupes helpful since its a very realistic view of the communities repsonses to these types of questions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That question didn't do well because it wasn't very specific. It was hard to tell what the OP wanted and SO isn't really a "give me links to tutorials" kind of site.

The topic of Keyloggers is irrelevant. It was just a bad question in general. Asking for tutorials is not a good question.

Comment: you say this however I thought I made it rather specific as to what I wanted and my requirements

Comment: Asking for tutorials is not a good question.